# R: How to handle raw/byte characters mixed with latin-1 characters

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, byte

I have some e-mails that have **raw** instead of latin-1 characters for æ,Æ,ø,Ø,å,Å.

```
# My string
my_string = "Den vedh=E6ftede"

# Should be
"Den vedhæftede fil"

# Raw character for E6
> charToRaw("æ")
[1] e6
```

Is there any way to convert the data back to the correct format other than to do a string replace?

```
# Naive solution (with potential problems)
> gsub("=E6", "æ", "Den vedh=E6ftede")
[1] "Den vedhæftede"
```

String replace has the problem if "=E6" exists naturally in the e-mails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW, that symbol has an `e6` raw representation if the encoding is `latin1`. In `UTF-8` its byte representation is `c3 a6` (2 bytes).

Comment: This looks like Microsoft's mangling behaviour. I'm pretty sure it escapes naturally occurring strings that would otherwise be transcoded to hex.

Comment: I just edited the "UTF-8" to the correct "latin1"